# Rubyripper crash before creating MP3 on 16.04

Tags: mp3, cd-ripping

Installed Rubyripper 0.6.2 and Lame 64 bit v3.99.5 on Ubuntu 16.04.  Configured lame codec using default entry in Rubyripper preferences (-V 3 --id3v2-only).

It starts off OK, then crashes out after trial2.  End of log file is:

```
STATUS
Starting to rip track 1, trial #1 (71 seconds)
Starting to rip track 1, trial #2 (71 seconds)
Analyzing files for mismatching chunks (0 second(s))
Every chunk matched 2 times :)
MD5 sum: e3a5baf7600c3d4469ec8c96b3ee4b2c
```

If I enable other codecs it produces the output file for that codec OK then crashes out before creating the MP3.

I'm sure this is a configuration issue, perhaps something needs to be installed that I haven't?  Anybody had this problem & resolved it?

Answer (score 2):

Rubyripper is long dead & wasn't developed past ruby-1.9.1, 16.04 is on 2.3.x

I'd find something else like asunder or abcde but that being said,  to fix mp3 do this

`sudo apt install ruby2.3-dev`

When that completes run this command

`sudo gem install iconv`

Then open rr again & it should be able to do mp3 encoding, tested here & does work.

Comment: Need to update to **Ruby 2.5.x (dev)**, so instead use: **`sudo apt install ruby-dev`**